# MPMoviePlayerViewController HTTP Authentication Header

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

I using the following basic commands to view a movie stored on a server in the movie player:

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController *mMoviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:getMovieURLRequest.URL];
[self presentModalViewController:mMoviePlayer animated:YES];
```

The problem is, I am getting a 401 authentication error when I try to access the file.  I have used NSURLRequest in the past where I can insert HTTP Headers for Basic Authentication, but I don't see how I can do that here with the MPMoviePlayerViewController since it only accepts the NSURL parameter in the init?

Any ideas or help is much appreciated.

Rob

Answer (score 0):

You can probably pre-populate the authentication info in the [shared `NSURLCredentialStorage` object](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLCredentialStorage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSURLCredentialStorage) so it's already there when the `MPMoviePlayerViewController` issues its own request via the URL loading system.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is a special issue/feature of the projects backend, but in my case it works absolutely fine, if I attach the (oAuth2)token as a get-param like this:

`https://my.domain.de/api/v1/get?access_token=<oAuthCredential.accessToken>`

Also I don't know if this might have some security disadvantages - but maybe it will help someone...